# Adjust Trackpoint speed on Lenovo P70 / Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, lenovo, trackpoint

I recently had to replace a failed keyboard on my Lenovo P70 running Ubuntu 22.04. Generally, everything is working fine, with one exception. The trackpoint (eraser in the middle of the keyboard) is VERY slow and I can't figure out how to adjust it. First I tried turning the speed up for both the touchpad and the mouse in the 'mouse and touchpad' settings dialog. The touchpad changes did take effect, though I don't use the touchpad so that's not much help. I don't use an external mouse, but I did confirm that those settings had no effect on the trackpoint. I've googled around a lot and tried a couple of things, but it seems like most of the suggestions are pretty old at this point, I'm skeptical that they are still relevant to 22.04.

```
Here is the output of 'input':
```

> ThinkPad-P70:~$ xinput WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland
> server. See the xinput man page for details. ⎡ Virtual core pointer
> id=2 [master pointer (3)] ⎜ ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer id=4 [slave
> pointer (2)] ⎜ ↳ xwayland-pointer:16 id=6 [slave pointer (2)] ⎜ ↳
> xwayland-relative-pointer:16 id=7 [slave pointer (2)] ⎜ ↳
> xwayland-pointer-gestures:16 id=8 [slave pointer (2)] ⎣ Virtual core
> keyboard id=3 [master keyboard (2)] ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard id=5
> [slave keyboard (3)] ↳ xwayland-keyboard:16 id=9 [slave keyboard (3)]

It's not even clear to me if one of those devices is the trackpoint. If so, which one?

Anyway, if anyone has any suggestions about how I could move forward here, I'd really appreciate it!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me; your mileage may vary. First, find your device:

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Synaptics TM3053-004                      id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
...
```

On my system, I see it as `TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint`. Next, find the acceleration property:

```
$ xinput list-props 'TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint' | grep Accel
    libinput Accel Speed (342): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (343): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (344):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (345):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (346):   1, 0
```

Here, I see it as `Accel Speed (342)`, and the `342` is what I need. After some experimentation, I was able to determine that the value, by default `0.000000` is expected to be in the range `[-1, 1]`. For me, `-0.2` ended up being a good speed:

```
$ xinput set-prop 'TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint' 342 -0.2
```